# search only on taxonomy and user autocomplete drupal 7

Tags: search

I would search only on **user and taxonomy** in autocomplete but not search in content. I try many modules :

1. Views Autocomplete
2. Filters  Search Autocomplete
3. Custom Search
4. Term Search

But none complete that ! any clues would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Filters Search Autocomplete works great for that but there a bug with entity Reference

> We can achieve this by following these steps:
>
> Add the required node reference field as relationship.
> Add a title field in fields and give them the above relationship.
> Add the title in combine filters.
> It Worked for me :)

[read more on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2450193)